# Insufficient privileges when trying to add schema extension to User

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to add custom properties to User object using `graph.microsoft.com`. I chose schema extensions for that, but the POST request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions` returns `Authorization_RequestDenied`.

First, I checked the permissions via the Azure CLI (the `id` is my app id):

```ps
az ad app permission list-grants --id 229e9b3d-5a17-4a46-930a-60e8ca114027 --show-resource-name
```

For Microsoft Graph, there are many permissions, but as I understand it, I should need only `User.ReadWrite.All` and `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` which are there.

Then I used Insomnia (to check functionality without coding problems) and call `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions` with JSON body:

```json
{
  "id": "extTest",
  "description": "test extension",
  "targetTypes": [
     "User"
  ],
  "properties": [
    {
      "name" : "isAvailable",
      "type" : "Boolean"
    }
  ]
}
```

and the returned response is:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "d5c1e7b3-f1c5-44c0-917d-5e43d7483bdf",
      "date": "2019-06-10T13:44:36"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there something I missed?

Comment: Can you please add an example of a token you've used? It would be helpful in determining what is going on.

Comment: It would also help to see the code you're using to make the call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your access token didn't have `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission. You can decode it by using https://jwt.io/ and check if this permission exists in 'scp'.

[image]

I have tested it on my side and it works. Here are my main steps.

1.add Directory.AccessAsUser.All permission to your app and **click grant admin consent button**.

[image]

2.get access token by using [auth code grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code#use-the-authorization-code-to-request-an-access-token). You can not use [client credential grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) here since you must sign in with a user.

Comment: Thank you, I really didn't have Directory.AccessAsUser.All in the token. My problem was that I used the client credential grant flow.